# How do I create a new table in SQL using the row values of another table as column names (dynamic)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

How do I create a new table in SQL using the row values of another table as column names? Please note the original table values are dynamic. Is dynamic Pivot the only option?

For example, if my old table looks like:

```
players
-----------
Lebron James
Kobe Bryant
Dwayne Wade
Chris Bosh
James Harden
```

I want the new table to look like:

```
Lebron James | Kobe Bryant | Dwayne Wade | Chris Bosh | James Harden
```

Comment: Will the fields in the tables be the same?  If so, why are you creating new tables?

Comment: essentially its the same once the previous queries are executed. but the number of values in the columns could could change. so I guess creating a new table isnt the crucible part. But I won't know what values will be in the column of the original table.

Comment: In that case, you'd be better off with one table and a field that differentiates the player that the record is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
DROP TABLE #players 
CREATE TABLE #players (name VARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO #players 
SELECT 'Lebron James'
UNION SELECT 'Kobe Bryant'
UNION SELECT 'Dwayne Wade'
UNION SELECT 'Chris Bosh'
UNION SELECT 'James Harden'


DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000)
SET @cmd ='CREATE TABLE MyNewTable (id INT'
SELECT @cmd = @cmd + '
, ['+name+'] VARCHAR(255)'
FROM #players

SELECT @cmd = @cmd + ')'

PRINT @cmd
EXEC(@cmd)

EXEC('SELECT * FROM MyNewTable')
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but the column for the original will be dynamic. this is static.